# Syntax Error on token "Extends" throws expected - when implementing a PhoneStateListener in a Service

Tags: java, android, service, listener, telephonymanager

I'm attempting to implement a phone state listener in a service and I'm getting the error:

```
Syntax error on token "extends", throws expected
```

but when I change `extends` to `throws` I get 3 new errors stating:

```
EndCallListener cannot be resolved to a type 
EndCallListener cannot be resolved to a type
No exception of type PhoneStateListener can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

Any suggestions?

Amani Swann

```
public void onCreate() extends PhoneStateListener {
  EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
  TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
 }

 public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
  if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
    // set number of calls to 1 in SharedPreferences                    
   SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
     .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
   Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("calls", "1");
   editor.commit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If onCreate is infact a method, as the return type "void" and the brackets after the name indicate, you can not use extends there. Only classes can inherid from other clases like that.

```
public class ClassName extends ParentClassName { //class code }
```

Here you find oracles [toutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) about inheritance.